# How to make a image spin/rotate around the z axis

Tags: wpf, image, rotation, storyboard

I would like to spin/rotate my Logo(Image) on the Z axis.

This is the code i have so far:

```
<Image Name="logo"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="someLogoPath" Width="140" Height="140" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="TransRotate" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Angle">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                         Storyboard.TargetName="TransRotate" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                         By="360" 
                         Duration="0:0:10"  
                         AutoReverse="False" 
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

This only spins it on the X axis.

What do i need to do, to get it to spin on the Z axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<Image.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform x:Name="TransRotate" CenterX="70" CenterY="70" />
</Image.RenderTransform>
```

or

```
<Image Name="logo" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I would actually like it to rotate on the x and z axis. Is it possible?

Comment: You could do a `ScaleTransform.ScaleX` `From="1"` `To="-1"` with `AutoReverse="True"` at the same time I think. I havn't tested it, but with `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` it should looks like a rotation on the x axis.